# Python pyglet RGB image is just black

Tags: python, pyglet, openai-gym

I want to display a numpy matrix as image in pyglet. I know that I have to use the ImageData interface for that, but when I do that, the image that is shown is just plain black. The same thing happens if I load an image with the Image interface, the image is just black. I am using the OpenAI gym infrastructure:

```
from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

viewer = rendering.Viewer(400, 400)
im = rendering.Image("img.png", 400, 400)
viewer.add_onetime(im)
rgb = viewer.render(return_rgb_array=True)
plt.imshow(rgb)
plt.show()
plt.savefig("out.png")
```

[image]

It makes no difference if I let pyglet render it to the screen or if I return the RGB array and plot it with matplotlib.
What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the exact same problem. Make sure the png has transparency enabled. This will at least plot the grayscale image. But I could not figure out how to make the gym viewer display RGB.

Comment: No, eventually I just used Matplotlib. It's much slower, but it allows drawing on a much higher level of abstraction, which is often very helpful.